# ListView add method does not add

Tags: java, android, listview, methods

I begin in Android/JAVA development and I'm stuck with the add method of my ListView. I'm trying to create a list with all the WiFi networks available. When I am calling the add method in the intern class WifiReceiver, nothing is happening. I don't understand. Could you explain this to me?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView mainText;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ListView list = null;
    List<String> wifiData = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifiData);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mainWifi.startScan();
        // mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
    {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
                wifiData.add(Integer.toString(i + 1) + "." + (wifiList.get(i)).toString());
            wifiData.add("Bite");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the list that something has changed. Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items.

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
            wifiData.add(Integer.toString(i + 1) + "." + (wifiList.get(i)).toString());
        wifiData.add("Bite");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This will also require you to make `adapter` a member variable so the inner-class knows about it. Simply declare it how you are with your other variables (outside of a method)

```
TextView mainText;
WifiManager mainWifi;
WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
List<ScanResult> wifiList;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ListView list = null;
List<String> wifiData = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and just initialize it in `onCreate()` how you are but without declaring it

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifiData);
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

After changing your list data, you need to notify your adapter that its content has actually changed with [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29). The easiest option would be declaring the adapter as an instance variable, in order to have access to it inside `WifiReceiver`.-

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```